# How narrow from cursor to end of buffer?

Tags: narrowing

```
M-x narrow-to-region   - Narrow down to between point and mark
```

But I need to narrow from cursor position to end of buffer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc-string of `narrow-to-region` tells us that the mandatory arguments are `START` and `END`:  "*When calling from a program, pass two arguments; positions (integers
or markers) bounding the text that should remain visible.*"

The programmatic location of cursor in the active buffer is `point`, and the end of the buffer (or end of narrowed region) is `point-max`.  Try typing `M-x eval-expression RET (narrow-to-region (point) (point-max)) RET` and see the result.  A shortcut for `eval-expression` is `M-:`.

Another idea would be to hold the shift key down and move the cursor to the end of the buffer and then `M-x narrow-to-region` aka `C-x n n`.

Comment: If you need this a lot you could define a command with the arguments suggested here. If it's an occasional thing I'd use: `C-SPC M-> C-x n n`, which would be `set-mark-command`, `end-of-buffer`, `narrow-to-region`.